# Determining Base URL using JSP

Tags: java, jsp

In the browser (IE and Firefox) if you have a relative link and your URL is: http://domain/somepath/lastfolder/

the relative link becomes:

```
http://domain/somepath/lastfolder/linkdocname.html
```

if the URL is http://domain/somepath/lastdoc the relative link becomes:

```
http://domain/somepath/linkdocname.html
```

http://domain/somepath/lastfolder/ becomes:

```
http://domain/somepath/lastfolder/linkdocname.html
```

Is there a way to replicate this using JSP without writing a special function?

I tried to get the base URL using:

```
baseURL = request.getScheme() + "://" + request.getServerName() + ":" 
+ request.getServerPort()+ request.getRequestURI();
```

but that gets me the whole path of the requst URI and doesn't drop off the last bit if it doesn't end in a "/"  Then if I try:

```
baseURL = request.getScheme() + "://" + request.getServerName() + ":" 
+ request.getServerPort() + request.getContextPath();
```

that gives me everything up to the web container folder but not any of the folders after that.

Answer (score 0):

In your last string building attempt you are missing a port number, even though you specified ":"

Try this:

```
new URL(request.getScheme(), request.getServerName(), 
        request.getServerPort(), request.getContextPath());
```

You can also build the string yourself and remove default ports if needed:

```
public String getBaseUrl(HttpServletRequest request) {
    if (( request.getServerPort() == 80 ) || ( request.getServerPort() == 443 )) {
        return request.getScheme() + "://" + request.getServerName() + 
                request.getContextPath();
    } else {
        return request.getScheme() + "://" + request.getServerName() + ":" + 
                request.getServerPort() + request.getContextPath();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I updated it.  The issue still exists.  request.getContextPath() gives me everything up to the web container name but not what the browser considers to be the base URL.

Comment: @user994165 , take a look at getServletPath and getPathInfo, here is an [example](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.servlet/GetReqUrl.html)